# Change wordpress website from having 2 columns to just 1

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

A website I have taken over has an odd setup, and 2 columns on each page. There is nowhere within WordPress I can see to change this manually.

https://kennifordfarm.co.uk/

Have tried all different CSS codes I have seen online but nothing changes. The second column seems to be dead apart from a link, and can't see where to add content for the 2nd column?

Answer (score 0):

You *can*  add this to your CSS, if you need a quick method:

```
.main-area, .otherside {
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, te better method would be to change the Bootstrap classes in the HTML of these two elements accordingly from `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12` (which will however require changing the php template files, which again would require to set up a child theme)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding that CSS makes no change at all sadly.

Comment: Probably because there are CSS rules with more specifity which overwrite it. You can try to add `!important`, like `width: 100% !important;`